# Select a child with a given class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three similar sections. I want to select an element with a given class but only within the scope of the element I clicked.

My current code selects *all* the elements with the same class.

If I add an event handler on class `mine`, and some action needed to be done on `target` class, only for the inner2 within the scope of class `one` I clicked,
so how do i do it.

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
 <div class="some">
      <div class="mine"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="inner1">
 </div>
 <div class="inner2">
   <div class="target"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="one">
  <div class="some">
      <div class="mine"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner1">
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
     <div class="target"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: selectors used in JS are not there in shared HTML. please post relevant markup.

Comment: I don't see any click event bind to class one.. would you like to revisit your question?

Comment: sorry, have a change in the questing, its the markup, check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : you can make use of [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get `inner2` element and do your operation on it.

```
$(".mine" ).click(function() {  
   $(this).siblings('.inner2').slideToggle(function(){
      if(temp==0){
        $(this).closest(".proElement").addClass('darkBg');
        temp=1;
     }
    else{
       $(this).closest(".proElement").removeClass('darkBg');
       temp=0;
      }
   });// end of slideToggle
}); //
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code . use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to search child element

```
$('.one').on('click',function(){
   var inner2Obj = $(this).find('div.inner2');
   inner2Obj.slideToggle(function(){
      // your code
   });
   console.log(inner2Obj) // this will log inner2 object within clicked one DIV
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use `sibling`

```
$(".mine" ).click(function() {  
$(this).siblings('.inner2').slideToggle(function(){
if(temp==0){
    $(this).closest(".proElement").addClass('darkBg');
    temp=1;
}
else{
    $(this).closest(".proElement").removeClass('darkBg');
    temp=0;
}
});
});
```

> **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7u7gs6m9/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .siblings() here:

```
$(".mine" ).click(function() {  
$(this).siblings('.inner2').slideToggle(function(){
if(temp==0){
    $(this).closest(".proElement").addClass('darkBg');
    temp=1;
}
else{
    $(this).closest(".proElement").removeClass('darkBg');
    temp=0;
}
});// end of slideToggle
}); // end of click
```